# Can live tiles be updated by taking values from the app without firing it in WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, live-tile

I have live tiles in my app and is not a web service app. Live tiles are updated on exiting of the app. So if the user does not open the app for a day it does not get updated.

Can I update without having to go to a server?? Can Tiles take the values from the app by firing the app by itself or can live tiles take values from app with out having the user opening it on a daily basis?

Alfah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you register a [PeriodicTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.periodictask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) and you will have 25 seconds to execute every 30 minutes, during which time you can update your live tiles.

See [Background Agents Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, I checked the API's which wont work for a Periodic Task, since IsolatedStorage does not appear in list, we would be able to access data from I isolated storage right?

Comment: @alfah - You can access isolated storage from a periodic task.

Comment: But don't forget to wrap access to it using a [global mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202944%28v%3Dvs.92%29.aspx) since your application and background task can be running at the same time